# http://192.168.1.1 not working

Tags: networking, ip, internet, router, port-forwarding

I am very new to this, so please bear with me here. I was looking to set up port forwarding for a game server. (Edit: TO HOST A MULTIPLAYER FLASH GAME ON MY IP ADRESS) I needed to log into my admin panel of the router to do that. But unfortunately I am not able to access admin panel using 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1 or 81.191.176.1 (default gateway).

The router I am using is from Zhone company. There is no wireless connected. But there are 3 other computers connected to the same router.
Below is the log from cmd when I type ipconfig in it.

```
C:\Users\Ankur>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : iad.ventelo.no
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e444:39ca:80c5:f794%
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 81.191.177.66
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 81.191.176.1

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : skagerak.org

Tunnel adapter isatap.iad.ventelo.no:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

C:\Users\Ankur>
```

How can I access the admin panel of the router?

Also, if it is not a relevant question to ask on stackoverflow, please comment and I will remove it.

EDIT:

After all the answers I am receiving I have just become more confused. I just wanted to host a multiplayer flash game on my own computer so that I did not have to bother about VPS and such. Are there any newbie tutorials for this. I decided to do port forwarding after I received an answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902837/newb-help-how-to-switch-from-localhost-to-webhost

Comment: You simply don't need do configure anything as you already have public IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your *DSL modem is in bridged mode. In this mode, the public IP address is passed directly to your connected computer, and the DSL device does nothing but shove packets back and forth.

In this case, you will set up Internet Connection Sharing on your connected computer, and have the other computers behind it. [Port forwarding in this scenario may require a third party tool](https://superuser.com/a/442693/144961).

Of course, if you're running the game server *on this same computer* then you don't need to forward any ports since the public IP address already terminates to it.

If you really want to put the *DSL modem in routed mode and do the port forwarding from it, check its user manual for the proper procedure (and default IP addres to connect to).

Comment: Hi, I do not understand how this will work in my case. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902837/newb-help-how-to-switch-from-localhost-to-webhost

Comment: Your IP address is 81.191.177.66 so that is what you will use.

Comment: Ummm, is it that simple? In this article from Smartfox server - http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/GettingStarted/installation (the server I am using to implement multiplayer functionality in my game), they talk about port forwarding and all this. I am confused. Can you explain to me in simple terms what is going on? Sry I am a newb

Comment: You don't need to port forward, because your game server is already on the machine with the public IP address!

Comment: It is indeed that simple. Port forwarding is necessary in typical home setups, but not in yours.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. But will that be all I need to do. They also talk about cloud service in this http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/GettingStarted/installation , do I need to put my game on a remote server or cloud service once I have got it working on my ip adress.

Comment: Only if you really want to. If you want to run it at home, that's OK too :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I want to put it on a website, I am using 000webhost. Can I just put it on the webhost normally or do I need to put it on a remote server or something like that? Thanks for all the help, I am going to accept your answer.

Comment: You can't put a game server on a shared hosting web site. You would have to use a VPS or dedicated server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ok, thanks very much, Accepted your answer! btw, do you know any free VPS services, even if they are like trial for like 3 months?

Comment: You can find _cheap_ ones at http://www.lowendbox.com/ :)

Answer (score 0):

The IPConfig output could mean your PC already has a global IP address. If you can't access a game server on your PC from the Internets, it could be because of e.g. firewall[s], either Windows firewall, or firewall of your router, of firewall of your ISP. If it's your ISP, sometimes changing the port # of your game server to a value greater then 1024 helps.

Just click on http://www.myipaddress.com/show-my-ip-address/, if it says your IP address is 81.191.177.66, it means your IP address is already external and no port forwarding is required (port forwarding only required if you have a NAT between you and the Internets).

Comment: I am not trying to connect to a game server, I am trying to host a game on my ip adress. I think you did not understand my question correctly.

Comment: @Ankur: You didn't understand his answer. He's saying that if people have an issue connecting to a game server _on your PC_, then it's a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a direct public IP on your computer ( 81.191.177.66 ).

That means there is no need to work around the problems of NAT and forward ports since you are not using NAT.

Comment: Hi Hennes, the reason I wanted to do port forwarding and stuff was to host my game server on my own ip adress as somebody suggested to me here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902837/newb-help-how-to-switch-from-localhost-to-webhost

Comment: What is stopping you?  Port forwarding is like having a central number with a secretary. You ask the secretary to forward some of the calls (some of the ports) to to an internal number.  Bu tin your case you have a direct line. No forwarding is needed.

Comment: But in this tutorial I was using - http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/GettingStarted/installation, it talks about port forwarding? Or am I doing something wrong?